# Twitter bootstrap Modal with Asp.net Webforms disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal with Asp.net Webforms.

After the event click the button **btnSubmit**, the modal disappears.

How to maintain the modal active?

Example.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Example.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
txtMessage.Text = "Success!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your UpdatePanel tags; where you have them at the moment you are enclosing the entire modal where you need to be only enclosing the modal content.

For example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```